# IIS URL rewrite based on accept headers and request type

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Is i possible to rewrite an URL using IIS, based on the Accept-headers and request type.

I need IIS to rewrite all URLS to index.html (A stateful js app) for the following conditions:

1. The request is a GET request
2. The accept headers from the client includes: "text/html"
3. Is not a direct file request. The requested path does not contain a . (DOT) character

I think its the same as the Node module: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, if I follow correctly your requirements I believe the URL Rewrite rule you need is below.
Basically,

1. use a condition to match the HTTP_METHOD to be a GET
2. use a condition to match HTTP_ACCEPT to make sure it starts with text/html since usually they also include encoding and other data
3. make sure it is not a file

   ```
       <rule name="Rewrite Text Requests">
           <match url=".*" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
               <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="^text/html" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
       </rule>
   ```